# Avoid destruction of object when executing futures in different threads

Tags: c++, c++11, future

Imagine the following situation:

```
class A {
 public:
  folly::Future<folly::Unit> fooA(std::function<void()> callback);
};

class B {
 public:
  void fooB() {
    a_->fooA([] { doSomethingCheap_(); })  /* Executed in thread 1 */
        .via(exec_.get())
        .then([] { doSomethingExpensive_(); }) /* Executed in thread 2 */
  }
 private:
  std::shared_ptr<folly::Executor> exec_;
  std::shared_ptr<A> a_;

  void doSomethingCheap_();
  void doSomethingExpensive_();
};
```

If at the time we end executing `doSomethingCheap_()` object `B b` will be destroyed then we will get `segfault`. Probably we can hold `weak_ptr<B>` in `class A`, but this approach is not extensible when we want to use `class A` not only in `class B` but also in some `class C`, ...

What is the best way avoiding it?

Comment: Expressions `doSomethingCheap_()` and `doSomethingExpensive_()` have type void and cannot be passed to other functions.

Comment: @aschepler, can you correct my code if you got the idea? Not so familiar with `std::function` but used it for the sake of example.

Comment: Is this what executor's `makeKeepAlive` is for?

Comment: Or maybe there's a nice way to use shared_ptrs to keep B alive? I don't see it, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with folly or what synchronization mechanisms you're using, but it seems like you could maybe use a Mutex-guarded bool that you capture and pass to the lambda calling doSomethingExpensive - this would be a "poor-man's join". Lock the mutex and then flip the bool to true. Alternately, you could use something like absl::Notification [since that what I know].

```
#include "absl/synchronization/notification.h"

class A {
 public:
  folly::Future<folly::Unit> fooA(std::function<void()> callback);
};

class B {
 public:
  void fooB() {
    a_->fooA([] { doSomethingCheap_(); })  /* Executed in thread 1 */
        .via(exec_.get())
        .then([this] {
                  doSomethingExpensive_();
                  finished_.Notify();
               }) /* Executed in thread 2 */
    finished_.WaitForNotification();
  }
 private:
  std::shared_ptr<folly::Executor> exec_;
  std::shared_ptr<A> a_;
  absl::Notification finished_;

  void doSomethingCheap_();
  void doSomethingExpensive_();
};
```

Ultimately, joining on the threads seems like the right way to go, I'm just not sure what is exposed in folly.